# What is selected with 'this' after .prependTo()?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('<div id="' + id + '"><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a> | <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a><br /><h1>' + title + '</h1><br /><p>' + content + '</p></div><hr>').prependTo('#content').hide().slideDown('normal');

addFunctionality(this);

function addFunctionality(scope){
   //Remove-section
   $('.remove', scope).click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); ...
   });
}
```

Shouldn't `this` refer to the inserted DOM elements? This way nothing happens if I click the link with the class `remove`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers the object in which object's context the function was called. If you're using the above code in your ready function, `this` is actually the whole HTML document. `this` can be used in jQuery event callbacks (like the click event) to refer to the DOM object which triggered the action. `this` never changes in the middle of a function, no matter what function you're calling.

To get what you wanted, save the returned jQuery object in a variable and pass that to your function:

```
var $elements = $('<div id="' + id + '"><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a> | <a href="#"
  class="remove">Remove</a><br /><h1>' 
  + title + '</h1><br /><p>' + content + '</p></div><hr>')
.prependTo('#content')
.hide().slideDown('normal');

addFunctionality($elements);

function addFunctionality(scope){
    //Remvoe-section
    $('.remove', scope).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this fits in to your existing code, but you might consider chaining `.find()` to select the `a.remove` elements you just created, thus:

```
$('<div id="' + id + '"><a href="#" class="edit">Edit</a> | <a href="#"
   class="remove">Remove</a><br /><h1>' 
   + title + '</h1><br /><p>' + content + '</p></div><hr>')
.prependTo('#content')
.hide().slideDown('normal')
.find('a.remove').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //...
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/find/

I'd also have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/ to clean up that convoluted element creation.

Comment: .find() would also work, but wouldn't be very handy in my code, because the function "addFunctionality" is used several times and does more then just add this event.
Thanks for the hint with the tamplate, i will have a look at it.